# Small Triangles, Large Triangles code not working

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct, swap

So, I had been trying to write the code for the Small Triangles, Large Triangles problem of C in Hackerrank. Before, I state what problem I'm facing, I'll attach the question-
[image]

I only wrote the sort_by_area, swap and area functions here. The rest of it was given and unchangeable. The code I've written is getting executed properly but the structures aren't getting sorted correctly. Here is the expected output & my output-

[image]

I just cannot figure out why it is getting such weirdly swapped. If anyone could help, would mean a lot.

My code is-

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    int i, j, swapped;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
     swapped = 0;
     for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
     {
        if (area(tr[j].a, tr[j].b, tr[j].c) > area(tr[j+1].a, tr[j+1].b, tr[j+1].c))
        {
           swap(&tr[j], &tr[j+1]);
           swapped = 1;
        }
     }
     if (swapped == 0)
        break;
    }
}
void swap(struct triangle **xp, struct triangle **yp)
{
    struct triangle *temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
int area(int a, int b, int c){
       int p=(a+b+c)/2;
       int q=p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c);
       return sqrt(q);
   }
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: I do understand that you are using the Heroon formula as a way to calculate the surface of a random triangle, but your three examples are all rectangular triangles, so you might use the "simple" surface formula in this case (3^2+4^2=5^2, same for (12,5,13) and (24,7,25)).

Comment: @Dominique Hi. Yup, I had considered that, but since they mentioned the Heron's formula in the question, thought of not changing it :3

Comment: Does your swap function is working as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enable all warnings**

This quickly led to `swap()` swapping pointers and not data.

```
// Corrected - swap data
void swap(struct triangle *xp, struct triangle *yp) {
  struct triangle temp = *xp;
  *xp = *yp;
  *yp = temp;
}
```

---

**Function order**

Move `area()`, `swap()` definitions before calling them.

---

**Area**

`(int) sqrt(q)` may return the same value for different `q`s.

Example: `(int) sqrt(100)`, `(int) sqrt(110)`, `(int) sqrt(120)`
All return 10.  Sorting will not certainly sort according to area.

---

Simple return the square of the area.  Mathematically, sorting by area squared same as area.

```
int area_squared(int a, int b, int c){
   int p=(a+b+c)/2;
   int q=p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c);
   // return sqrt(q);
   return q;
}
```

---

Although one could code using `double`, let us stay with integers.

Watch out for `a+b+c` as odd as `odd/2` forms a truncated quotient.

Perhaps return the square of the area, scaled each side by 2?

```
int area_squared2(int a, int b, int c){
   a *= 2; b *= 2; c *= 2;
   // a+b+c is certianly even
   int p=(a+b+c)/2;
   int q=p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c);
   return q;
}
```

A remaining concern is `int` overflow.  Consider `long long` math.

```
long long area_squared2LL(int a, int b, int c){
   long long aa = a * 2LL;
   long long bb = b * 2LL;
   long long cc = c * 2LL;
   long long pp = (aa+bb+cc)/2;
   long long qq = pp*(pp-aa)*(pp-bb)*(pp-cc);
   return qq;
}
```

---

**Tip: Allocate by referenced data, not type**

Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
triangle *tr = malloc(sizeof *tr * n);
if (tr == NULL) {
  // use tr 
  ...
  free(tr);
  tr = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <math.h>

   struct triangle
  {
       int a;
       int b;
       int c;
  };

  typedef struct triangle triangle;
  typedef struct triangle tr_temp;

  void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n)
 {
       int i, j, min;
       triangle tr_temp[100];
       double p[101], s[101], area[100], temp_area;
       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
            p[i] = (tr[i].a + tr[i].b + tr[i].c)*(0.5);
            s[i] = sqrt(p[i]*(p[i]-tr[i].a)*(p[i]-tr[i].b)*(p[i]-tr[i].c));
            area[i] = s[i];    
      }
      //To check whether areas are calculated correctly or not
      /*for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
            printf("%d %d %d :- %lf\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c, 
            area[i]);
       }*/
      for (i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
          for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
          {
                if (area[i] > area[j])
                {
                     temp_area = area[i];
                     area[i] = area[j];
                     area[j] = temp_area;

                     tr_temp[i].a = tr[i].a;
                     tr[i].a = tr[j].a;
                     tr[j].a = tr_temp[i].a;

                     tr_temp[i].b = tr[i].b;
                     tr[i].b = tr[j].b;
                     tr[j].b = tr_temp[i].b;

                     tr_temp[i].c = tr[i].c;
                     tr[i].c = tr[j].c;
                     tr[j].c = tr_temp[i].c;
                    /*tr_temp = tr[i];
                     temp_area = area[i];
              
                    tr[i] = tr[j];
                    area[i] = area[j];

                    tr[j] = tr_temp;
                    area[j] = temp_area;*/
                }
           }
        }
   }           


   int main()
  {
       int n;
       scanf("%d", &n);
       triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
       }
      sort_by_area(tr, n);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
      }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).